# eCPM and Est. Earning not counting in my admob?

Tags: android, admob

I have developed an app and posted two types of admob ads on application. Interstitial ads and Banner ad.
Interstitial ads are being counted. Impressions, RPM, eCPM, earning every thing working fine but Banner Ads only showing Requests,Match rate and Impressions. No est. earning and no RPM, eCPM. 
What is the problem?

**BANNER AD NOT COUNTING EARNING**
[image]

**INTERSTITIAL AD WORKING FINE**
[image]

> NOTE: Both types of ads are from same account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banner ads generate income only when they are clicked i.e to get income from banner ads you need to get the user to click on the ads however when it comes to interstitial ads they do not require any user interaction hence even if they are viewed they'll generate income.

Comment: Are you sure? I have read somewhere that admob also pay you for impressions but very little.

Comment: Yes i'm damn sure for banner ads you will be only paid when user clicks on it